# React: How to map a geojson via fetch call to state using leaflet?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I am trying to map out a geojson that I am fetching in `react` and using `react-leaflet`. I am able to map the geojson when I import it locally. Now I am fetching the raw data via https and then setting state to try to pass that state as props. But nothing maps from `this.state.geojson`.

I think I might be setting state wrong or misunderstanding how the rendering works. Some guidance would be appreciated. Below is some of the code:

**App.js**

```
...
  fetchData = async () => {
      let data = await
        fetch(
          "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/timwis/leaflet-choropleth/gh-pages/examples/basic/crimes_by_district.geojson"
          )
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((geojson) => {
            return geojson
          })

      console.log("my_data: ", data)
      this.setState({ geojson: data, loaded: 2 })
      return data
}
...

 {/** MAP */}
            <div>
              {this.state.geojson && <Leaf
                viewPort={this.state.viewPort}
                geojson={this.state.geojson} 
              />}
            </div>
...
```

**Leaf.js**

```
...
<Map>
...
<Choro
  geojson={this.props.geojson}
/>
</Map>
```

**Choro.js**

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useLeaflet } from "react-leaflet";
var L = require('leaflet')
require('leaflet-choropleth')


function Choro(props) {
    const { map } = useLeaflet();
  
    useEffect(() => {
      fetch(
        //"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/timwis/leaflet-choropleth/gh-pages/examples/basic/crimes_by_district.geojson"
        `${props.geojson}`  
      )
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((geojson) => {
          L.choropleth(geojson, {
            valueProperty: "DIFF", // which property in the features to use
            scale: ["white", "red"], // chroma.js scale - include as many as you like
            steps: 5, // number of breaks or steps in range
            mode: "q", // q for quantile, e for equidistant, k for k-means
            //style,
            onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
              layer.bindPopup(
                "Total " +
                  feature.properties.DIFF +
                  "<br>" //+
                  // feature.properties.incidents.toLocaleString() +
                  // " incidents"
              );
            }
          }).addTo(map);
        });
    }, []);
  
    return null;
 }

 export default Choro;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change of state should occur inside `then` and not outside:

```
fetchData =  () => {
      fetch(
          "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/timwis/leaflet-choropleth/gh-pages/examples/basic/crimes_by_district.geojson"
          )
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((geojson) => {
             console.log("my_data: ", geojson);
             this.setState({ geojson, loaded: 2 })

          })

}
```

However, I am not still sure what you are doing because you are fetching the geojson on `App` and then you pass the data to Leaf and then to `Choro` (this is called prop drilling) and then you are using the geojson as a url to re fetch the data. If you have fetched the data on App why to re fetch them on `Choro`? And most importantly you use as url the `geojson` data. Take another look on your code.

Last but not least when you are using `then` `then` you cannot use at the same time `async` `await` because these two serve exactly the same purpose. They are used to make an async call in a synchronous way.

this is how it should be [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-how-to-map-a-geojson-via-fetch-call-to-state-using-leaflet-fimu2?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: I greatly appreciate this answer. It was so helpful and insightful. Thank you so much for your help. I have upvoted and set this as the correct answer.

Comment: I do notice that if I refetch a different geojson via a button click, the new geojson data is plotted, but on top of the existing choropleth instead of replacing it. It's as if I need to re-render the choropleth function. Any idea how this might be solved?

Comment: You need to clear the map before adding new layers

Comment: I can't just run `this.setState({ geojson: null })` right? I need to clear the map in some other way? Appreciate the guidance.

Comment: this is the variable that holds the `geojson` data. You need to clear the layers from the `map` instance.

Comment: Since this is a different question entirely I created a new post for it, if you get the chance and are able to help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65397400/how-do-i-clear-a-leaflet-map-in-react-so-i-can-map-fresh-data